# How to configure SingleThreadScheduledExecutor to run a job every 15mins between 8am to 10am and then every 1hr throughout the day

Tags: java, scala, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I need some assistance on how to implement the SingleThreadScheduledExecutor to run the job every 15mins between 8 am to 10 am UK time and then every 1hr throughout the day.

Currently, I have the following Scala code -

```
val pollingExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new NamedThreadFactory("MyTestScheduledThread"))

pollingExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyRunnableJob(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Comment: Looks good. What's the problem with this?

Comment: @stefanobaghino - it's running every 15mins throughout the day. I want to change to run for 15mins between 8am to 10am and then run every 1hr.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this is something you want to do from within a Java process? It looks like a cronjob could be a better choice, but of course you know your requirements better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a wrapper around the job that takes care of scheduling:

```
class ScheduledRun(
   job: Runnable, 
   scheduler: ScheduledExecutorService
 )(delay: => Duration) extends Runnable {
   def schedule(): Unit = delay match {
     case d: FiniteDuration => scheduler.schedule(this, d.toMillis, MILLISECONDS)
     case _ => 
   }
   def run(): Unit = {
     job.run()
     schedule()
   }
}
```

And then you can just do:

```
new ScheduledRun(myRunnableJob, pollingExecutor)(
   if (isMorningInUK) 15 minutes else 1 hour
).schedule
```